# How do I format numbers in parameters of TranslatePipe?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

My `en.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "errorMin": "Value must be over {{min}}."
}
```

I've got an object that looks like:

```
err = {
    "min": 25000, 
    "actual": 654
}
```

In my template, I did:

```
{{ 'errorMin' | translate: err }}
```

This works great and outputs:

```
Value must be over 25000.
```

But I'd like to format the `min` parameter.  Similar to how `{{ 25000 | number }}` will output `25,000`.

Can that be accomplished with ngx-translate?

It'd be cool if I could just add the NumberPipe inside `en.json`, like:

```json
{
    "errorMin": "Value must be over {{min | number}}."
}
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try `{{ 'errorMin' | translate: {min: (25000 | number)} }}`?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I've over simplified my question.  Yes, that would work with my example, but what if  `{min: 25000}` comes from a larger object with other parameters?  I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the values yoy want to insert into the translation string inside the object as formatted string, not as number.

You could map your object before passing to the translate pipe
or use a inline object inside the html template like:

```
{{ 'errorMin' | translate: {min: (err.min | number), actual: err.actual} }}
```